# What's the easiest way to create a grid view with UI buttons?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm creating a dead-simple app that will only be in landscape mode. I'm trying to create a 4x4 grid without all the fuss of adding a collection view (preferably just using constraints). First, is this possible? Next, what is the best practice for this? When I add constraints to the first button, it automatically resizes to a larger button. When I add constraints to the second button relative to the first button, the button gets wider again. I don't understand, and I really only want to learn what is necessary for this project without tons of excess stuff.

I've attached a screenshot of the rough layout that I'm looking for. I appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

[image: rough layout without constraints]

Comment: I think a `UIStackView` would be the way to go if it's going to be a finite number of buttons. You could do a vertical stack view with 4 row and then within each row, just do a horizontal stack with 4 buttons of equal width.

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage the power of `UIStackView`'s. It is less constraints and has a distribution property with `Fill equally` value so that your buttons have the same size.

For this you can add a parent vertical `UIStackView` and constraint it top,left,right,bottom of its supverView then you can add 2 horizontal `UIStackViews` inside of it that contains buttons. Just set the buttons width and height and set the `UIStackViews` distribution to fill equally.

You can chech the apple's docu about this for further info https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

Good day :)

Comment: Yes, I was playing around with the stack view and it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Sky.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you can use `UIKit` component `UIStackView` which gives us a flexible view container that makes it even easier to build complex layout like you want and it also allows to layout views in **stack (either in horizontal or vertical stack)**.

You can also check more info here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

You can take reference from here for your design:

https://medium.com/@khfarooq/ios-autolayouts-and-stack-views-101eae224480

Comment: Thank you, Kishan. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function below that will dynamically resize your buttons and spacing between them:

```
func drawHrsButtons(){

    let offset = 10 // set offset on X & Y axes
    
    let btnsOnX = 4 // how many buttons in row
    let btnSize = (Int(self.frame.width) - (offset * (btnsOnX + 1))) / btnsOnX // calculate size dynamically
    
    print("offset: \(offset)")
    print("size: \(btnSize)")
    print("view width: \(Int(self.frame.width))")

    var xRow = 0
    var xPosMultiplier = 0
    
    for i in 0..<24{  // total 24 buttons to create, each row has 4 buttons

        xPosMultiplier += 1
        
        if (i % btnsOnX == 0) { // change row each 4x
            xRow += 1
            xPosMultiplier = 0
            print("")
        }
       
        let xPos = offset + (xPosMultiplier * offset) + (xPosMultiplier * btnSize)
        let yPos = (offset + (xRow * offset) + (xRow * btnSize)) - (btnSize + offset)
        
        let btnTitle = String(format: "%02d", i) + String(format: "-%02d", i + 1)
        
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(xPos), y: yPos + 25, width: CGFloat(btnSize), height: CGFloat(btnSize)) // 20 - offset from top buttons
        btn.tag = i
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        btn.setTitle(btnTitle, for: UIControlState())
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: UIControlState())
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hrsButtonSelected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(btn)
        
       // print("spacing: \(spacing), multiplier: \(xPosMultiplier), xPos: \(xPos), yPos: \(yPos), btnSize: \(btnSize)")
        
        
        if (i % btnsOnX  == 0) { // change row each 4x
            xPosMultiplier = 0 // reset with new row after x was set
        }
    }
}
```